# "-" not working while trying to simulate a calculator

Tags: java

I have to (it's homework) simulate the behavior of a calculator in Java with a switch-case. When I enter the numbers and the operator and I chose "/", "%", "*" or "+", it works perfectly. But when I chose "-", it prints for example "6 - 2 = 0.0", which is the default value of res. Why is that and how to fix it please ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b;
        String operator;
        double res = 0.0;
        boolean invalid_operator = false;
        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        a = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter operator");
        operator = scanner.next();
        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        b = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.close();
        
        switch(operator) {
          case "/":
            res = (double)a/(double)b;
            break;
          case "*":
            res = (double)a*(double)b;
            break;
          case "+":
            res = (double)a+(double)b;
            break;
          case "-":
            res = (double)a-(double)b; //not working at the moment
          case "%":
            res = (double)a%(double)b;
            break;
          default:
            System.out.println("Invalid operator");
            invalid_operator = true;
        }
        if(!invalid_operator){
            System.out.println(a+" "+operator+" "+b+" = "+res);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried 6 and 2 for every operation. I expect it to calculate correctly.

Comment: You forgot the `break`

Comment: There is one very obvious difference between the working operators and the nonworking one...

Comment: By the way, you may want to research Shunting Yard algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `break;` after your '-' line.

Add it in here:

```
case "-":
    res = (double)a-(double)b; //not working at the moment
    break; //here
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... When I enter the numbers and the operator and I chose "/", "%", "*" or "+", it works perfectly. But when I chose "-", it prints for example "6 - 2 = 0.0", which is the default value of res. Why is that and how to fix it please ? ..."*

You're missing a *break* keyword.

```java
case "-":
    res = (double)a-(double)b;
    break;
```

Use the newer *[switch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/language/switch-expressions.html)* syntax, which infers a *break* keyword.

Additionally, use the *[Scanner#nextDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble())* method over the *nextInt*, considering you are casting to a *double* later on.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String operator;
double a, b, res;
boolean invalid_operator = false;
System.out.println("Enter first number");
a = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter operator");
operator = scanner.next();
System.out.println("Enter second number");
b = scanner.nextDouble();
scanner.close();
res = switch (operator) {
    case "/" -> a / b;
    case "*" -> a * b;
    case "+" -> a + b;
    case "-" -> a - b;
    case "%" -> a % b;
    default -> {
        System.out.println("Invalid operator");
        invalid_operator = true;
        yield 0;
    }
};
if(!invalid_operator){
    System.out.println(a+" "+operator+" "+b+" = "+res);
}
```

Finally, you should check *operator* during its assignment, rather than during the calculation.
This will remove the need for *invalid_operator*.

```java
...
System.out.println("Enter operator");
while (!(operator = scanner.next()).matches("[/*+%-]")) {
    System.out.println("Invalid operator");
    System.out.println("Enter operator");
}
...
res = switch (operator) {
    case "/" -> a / b;
    case "*" -> a * b;
    case "+" -> a + b;
    case "-" -> a - b;
    case "%" -> a % b;
    default -> 0;
};
System.out.println(a+" "+operator+" "+b+" = "+res);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your knowledge sharing !